# return intStream of square numbers

Tags: java

```
public static void randomSquare() 
{

    int[] array = new Random().ints(10).toArray();
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

I currently have this method which returns random numbers. How would I modify it so it returns a stream of 10 square numbers instead?

Comment: This actually returns nothing.

Comment: What is a 10 square number and how is it related to the code you have posted? You want a stream of 10 random numbers that are squared or you want a stream of numbers that are squares of multiples of 10?

Comment: My code should return a stream of numbers that are squares

Answer (score 3):

If you want to square the random numbers, change

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(10).toArray();
```

to

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(10).map(x -> x*x).toArray();
```

However, this may result in integer overflow, so you might want to limit the range of the random integers. For example:

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(10,1,100).map(x -> x*x).toArray();
```

Also, you can init the Random first, like

```
static final Random RAND = new Random();
```

and then use

```
int[] array = RAND.ints(10,1,100).map(x -> x*x).toArray();
```

if you want to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can change your line of code to:

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(10).map(x -> x*x).toArray();
```

However your method at the moment does not return nothing. You use void keyword. Void doesn't return anything. It tells the compiler the method doesn't have a return value.
You can use int[], to return int array.

```
    public static int[] randomSquare() 
{

    int[] array = new Random().ints(10).map(x -> x*x).toArray();
    //some code, method logic etc.
    return array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding to [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49401552/4405757).

If you don't want to limit the range, you could use a `BigInteger`

```
List<BigInteger> bigIntegers = new Random().ints(10)
        .mapToObj(i ->{
            BigInteger intAsBigInteger = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
            return intAsBigInteger.multiply(intAsBigInteger);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(bigIntegers);
```